# How do I check if a string doesn't exist and then return false?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make my code return false if the $str doesn't exist

Here is what I tried (but didn't work):

```
function rev_epur_str($str)
{
    $str = implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str)));
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
    if (isset($str)) 
    {
        return $str;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
var_dump(rev_epur_str());
```

Output says:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for rev_epur_str()
```

It just returns an error instead of false

```
var_dump(rev_epur_str("")); // returns string(0) "" instead of FALSE
```

How do I return false if `$str` is empty?

Comment: Did not work, so what you got to see instead?

Comment: can you show us the place where you call the function `rev_epur_str`? you are supposed to give it a string as argument

Comment: @Kaddath Just edited it to be more clear

Comment: That is the expected output as `$str` is required. If you want, you can make `$str` optional and `return false` if it is empty / not set, though that would make it long winded.

Comment: @Script47 How do I return false if $str is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in PHP set the default value of a parameter. The code below makes `$str` an optional parameter and at the same time, it does an [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) check to return false.

```
function rev_epur_str($str = '')
{
    if (empty($str))
      return false;

    $str = implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str)));
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);

    return $str;
}

var_dump(rev_epur_str()); // false

var_dump(rev_epur_str('str')); // rts
```

**Note:** The error shown in your original code is completely valid, you have set that your function takes a parameter therefore you *must* pass a parameter to it, that is, unless you use a default value for said parameter (which is what has been done above).

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/DeliriousRudeMacro)

**Reading Material**

[Default Arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a boolean, echo string, so you can be sure if its working fine:

```
function rev_epur_str($str)
{
    $str = implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str)));
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
    if (isset($str)) 
    {
        echo $str;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Comment: It just returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function like

var_dump(rev_epur_str($str));

Means $str should have some value;

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an error because you declare an argument to your function and you call it without any.

One way to work around this and allow a call to your function without argument is to declare a default value like this (here with the value `NULL`):

```
function rev_epur_str($str = NULL)
{
    //code here
}
rev_epur_str(); //will work
```

Also, testing `isset` will only work if the variable never was set or is NULL. If you want it to work with empty string you can try with:

```
if (empty($str))
{
     return false;
}
//etc
```